# why my method that reads a text file takes too long

Tags: java, maven

i am new to java i made a simple application (tool) that take a list of words from text file then for each word it should look up its meaning in a dictionary, the app can take English words and look up its meaning in the Arabic dictionary, and vice versa every thing is fine in the code but the problem is when reading a text file it takes a long time like hours to read it.. the text file contains more than 3000 lines each line may have 10 or more words. the method to read files is like this:

```
public static void ChooseFile() throws IOException {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run()
{
     try {
         int h = 0 ;
         int b =0 ;
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "
                    + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());

            System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                    + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        //progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "\r\n")) != null) {
           line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
            String g;
             //g =  g.replace("\\s+", "/n");
            Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","").replaceAll("\\p{Digit}",""));
            while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
                // find next line

                g = inFile1.next();
                lines.add(g);
            progressBar.setVisible(true);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
              h++ ;
            ResultField.setText(lines.toString());
            ResultField.validate();
            }

            //  lines.add(line);
            System.out.println(lines);



        }

        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}}).start();  


} // End of choose file  .
```

I've Edited the code to: 
            public static void ChooseFile() throws IOException {

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run()
{
     try {
         int h = 0 ;
         int b =0 ;
        chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "
                    + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());

            System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
                    + chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        //progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String g;
             //g =  g.replace("\\s+", "/n");
            Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","").replaceAll("\\p{Digit}",""));
            while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
                // find next line
                g = inFile1.next();
            lines.add(g);
          //  progressBar.setVisible(true);
          //  progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
              h++ ;
          //  ResultField.setText(lines.toString());
           // ResultField.validate();
            }

            //  lines.add(line);
            System.out.println(lines);



        }

        reader.close();
        //progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        ResultField.setText(lines.toString());
         ResultField.validate();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}}).start();  


} // End of choose file  .
```

it still takes time but now it is much much  faster many thanks ..

Comment: Don't you get `NullPointerException`?`(line = bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+", "\r\n")) != null)` This line should be throwing `NPE` it when reaching `EOF`.

Comment: hmm .. actually no, never happened @Sanket Makani

Comment: Try running the code in debug mode and use break points to find the line causing the issue. Since you don't get a NPE, I suspect something wrong with your loops.

Comment: @AbdulazizAbdulah You are mistaken. It is **absolutely impossible** not to get a `NullPointerException` with this code, when you get to end of file. You need to  check the result of `readLine()` for null *before* doing anything else whatsoever with it, such as calling `replaceAll()`. It s also impossible for `replaceAll()` to return null. Your code doesn't make sense. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. And your `line.replaceAll()` does exactly nothing, as the result isn't assigned. Try debugging your code.

Comment: @EJP you are right it does show a NullPointerException it wasn't i guess because it was taking so long which led me to stop the program then reduce the text file manually. an armature move but i had at least solve the problem without stop my progress .. any how I've modified it now hope its better now. the new line is:  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null). thank you all for the responds.

Comment: The time is presently now being spent entirely in `System.out.println(lines);`, which is entirely pointless anyway as it keeps printing out the same stuff with only one difference each time. If you want to claim that file reading is slow, make sure you aren't doing anything else wasteful at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Constantly updating the GUI might be slow. I you really want an intermediate result. Multithread it, so the actual reading is not hindered (as much). Otherwise, move it to the end of the loop.

Also, you use this `.replaceAll("\\s+", "\r\n"))` to replace all whitespace with a new line and then iterate over each new line. You'd be better off with `line.split(...)`

Since in `.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","").replaceAll("\\p{Digit}","")` you remove these characters both times, you can just do this with one call of replaceAll.

Comment: exactly I've removed the repetitive GUI updates now it is faster.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calls `ResultField.setText(lines.toString())` and `ResultField.validate()` most likely take a long time in total. You are calling them every time a word is processed. For a file with 3000 lines and 10 words a line that is 30000 times. I do not see a reason why you would want to call them in the middle of the loop. Move those calls to be executed after the loops.

Comment: well i wanted it to show the file in real time but it turned out to be not a good approach. i should find a better way.. still learning.